# AWS Device Farm: *-tests.jar file is built after the zip file in the test package

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, appium, junit4

I have followed the configuration from the docs on AWS.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html#test-types-android-appium-java-junit-prepare

but jar file with extension `-tests.jar` is built after the zip file has been built. How to overcome this, I mean how to built the tests.jar file first then built zip file from pom.xml.

Here are plugins from my pom.xml file

```
<pluginManagement>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>test-jar</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <finalName>zip-with-dependencies</finalName>
              <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
              <descriptors>
                <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
              </descriptors>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Let me know if I can run them in an order using the plugins mentioned above.
Could someone help me with fixing this, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have reordered the plugin related -test.jar from plugin managements from above to below then it seems to be working by building -test.jar extention into zip file.

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.7.0</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.22.1</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.2</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>8</source>
      <target>8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>test-jar</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <finalName>zip-with-dependencies</finalName>
          <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
          <descriptors>
            <descriptor>zip.xml</descriptor>
          </descriptors>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Yes, order matters in a pom.xml file. Here is a sample pom you can compare with https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-device-farm-appium-tests-for-sample-app/blob/master/pom.xml